# Why does MySQL create 4 connections for the same user?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net, asp.net-web-api2, mysql-connector

I have Web API 2 application written in VB.NET. The `API` connects to a `MySQL` database. The user can do a lot of operations, fetching different kinds of data there are a lot of different GET/POST methods inside the controller.

I was wondering just why when the user does their first operation with the REST service, MySQL creates 4 connections for the same user?

All the methods to fetch or insert data are written with `Using` method so I'm sure that all connections are disposed properly.

Each user will be logged in and will do operations on its own database. But here is how the User connections list looks like when I'm logged with one user only:

[image]

Here is how one of `GET` methods is written:

```
    <HttpGet()>
    <Route("confirm")>
    Public Function ConfirmPrenotazioni(ByVal id As String)
        Try
            'Here i'm fetching the DB name from jwt token to connect the user
            Dim token As String = Request.Headers.GetValues("jwt_token").First()
            Dim principals = TokenManager.Principals(TokenManager.GetPrincipal(token))
            If principals Is Nothing Then Return New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            Dim reservation As Reservation = New Reservation

            Return reservation.ConfirmPrenotazione(id, principals.piva)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        End Try

    End Function
```

And here is how the ConfirmPrenotazione is written:

```
  Public Function ConfirmPrenotazione(ByVal id As String, ByVal piva As String) As String
        Dim SQLConnect As String = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=" & piva & ";Uid=root;Pwd=tax;"
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection(SQLConnect)
            cn.Open()
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE prenota_tavoli SET STATO_PTV = 'ARR', ORAARRIVO_PTV = @Oraarrivo WHERE ID_PTV = @Id AND STATO_PTV NOT LIKE('%ARR%')", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Oraarrivo", Format(Date.Now.AddMinutes(15), "yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm") & ":00")
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Return "OK"
            End Using
        End Using

        Return "ERR"
    End Function
```

Comment: ADO.NET uses connection pooling (to improve performance, mostly). So there is not a 1 <-> 1 mapping between the connection objects you create in your code and the real database connections which .NET Framework actually maintains the background. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-pooling.html

Comment: P.S. **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so if there are accidental security bugs in your application, 
this leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.